# How to stop form auto-reset in JS and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form that is defined as follows:

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="validate()">
```

I process information and then modify the body of the HTML as follows:

```
var toRemove = document.getElementById("formContainer");
toRemove.parentNode.removeChild(toRemove);
document.getElementById("main").childNodes[1].innerHTML = text1;
document.getElementById("main").childNodes[3].innerHTML = text2;
```

This displays corectly for a milisecond maybe, but then the page resets to the blank form.  I can fix this by adding an alert afterwards, but as soon as I dismiss the alert the page resets.  Is there a way to stop it from resetting?

Here is the full code:

HTML - http://puu.sh/p7HIl/e1abcc7920.html
JavaScript - http://puu.sh/p7HJ3/54850f8588.js

Also here is a live version - http://139.62.210.151/~n00876544/assign2/index.html?firstName=Cameron&lastName=Bixby&age=21-30&email=Other&baduk=yes

Comment: Could you post more code? There's not really much to work with here

Answer (score 2):

I presume the js snippets are written inside `validate` function

If it is so you can use `event.preventDefault()`  function which will block the default behavior .

```
function validate(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  //Rest of the code
}
```

Note: This will stop from submitting the form. But you can use `ajax` to send form data

Comment: I'm not familiar with `ajax`, but this is for a class so I doubt I can use other languages.  This auto-reset isn't a problem I have to fix for the assignment, but I'd like to anyways.

Comment: It seems you aren't planning to send the form data to a server (as you're evidently processing information and outputting response with JavaScript) so preventing that default behavior as described should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.  If I had to send data to a server is there any other way to do this?  Is the `ajax` solution simple?

Comment: @Pareod yes ajax is very simple. It is even simpler If you intend to you jquery

Answer (score 1):

The classic method to prevent form submission was to return false from the event handler, as in

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="validate(); return false;">
```

or if the validate function returns false to prevent submission, as

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="return validate();">
```

You can also prevent the default action by calling `preventDefault` on the event object.  The event object is passed as the first parameter to event handler functions, or set as a window property in older versions of IE. In either case you
can prevent the default immediately,

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); validate();">
```

or pass it to the validation routine where perhaps `preventDefault` can be called conditionally.

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="validate(event)">
```

Note that [HTMLelement.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) functionality provides an alternative to writing javascript event handlers as HTML attribute values and has the advantage of minimizing conflicts between multiple scripts trying to set the same " onEvent" HTML element attribute on the same HTML element.