# How can I stop a post method form from clearing all the input values on submit? (HTML/JS)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

So basically, I have a form with a post method. When I click submit, I can work with the POST superglobal values in PHP, but it clears all the textbox and radio button values and that's what I want to prevent.
(I don't think my code is important, just a basic form, nothing special).
Tried adding `onsubmit="return false"` in my HTML form tag, but then my submit button did nothing.
I tried these, none of them worked: 
[How to stop form auto-reset in JS and HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37495268/how-to-stop-form-auto-reset-in-js-and-html) 
[How to stop the form from resetting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43321805/how-to-stop-the-form-from-resetting)

So, how can I prevent the form from clearing all the data but do the POST method?

Comment: You either need to use Ajax to send the form data to a PHP script, or use the `value` attribute on the form elements to re-insert the value when the page is reloaded by the form (e.g `value="<?= $_POST['input_name'] ?>"`).

Comment: you can print the values again with PHP, or save the values in browser session storage

Comment: A form submit works just like any other page request / link, in that the current web page is a replaced with a new one. Unless the new form fields are prefilled by your PHP script, they'll show up empty as declared.

Comment: you need in this case to submit from ajax request

Comment: Or, if you don't want to do it with PHP, prevent the default and use [`serialize`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and [`$.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/);